# How to export CSV data of area from Google Earth

Tags: python, csv, google-earth, representation

1. I want to export CSV data of some area in Google Earth.
2. I will then import this data into python and run a 3d map.
3. I will be able to rotate and scale it then.

I can do the last 2 steps, but how can I do the 1st step?

I want to export it like [that](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv) with that code:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
# here read data:
z_data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv')
# plot it:
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z_data.values)])

fig.update_layout(title='Mt Bruno Elevation', autosize=False,
                  width=500, height=500,
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))

fig.show()
```

This code plots a 3-dimensional view on the example of CSV data. It can be scaled or rotated.

Any help?

Comment: What happens, when you run the code you posted? What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? Currently your question is a bit vague.

Comment: @Erik I have edited. If you will find more problems, just say. Thanks!